# How to insert selected records into the another table in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have created a Form1 in Visual Basic 2008 and on that Form1 I have placed two TextBoxes, Two DateTimePicker and one Button. Further in M. S. Access I have created a database with Two tables tableA and tableB. Here I want to retrieve selected records only from tableA and Insert into tableB.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button1.Click

    Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\TAMBE-DATABASE\SANJAY_PUNE.mdb")
    Connection.Open()
    Command = New OleDbCommand(" insert into tableB select * FROM tableA ", Connection)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Command.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()
    MsgBox("Records Added Successfully")
End Sub
```

When I try to execute it all the rows have been added into the table B. I don't want to add all the records. I want to add only selected rows. When I change in selected stated statement as

```
Command = New OleDbCommand(" insert into tableB select * FROM tableA where DATE_OF_SELL BETWEEN '" & TextBox1.Text "' AND '" & TextBox2.Text "'", Connection)
```

Here in text boxes I have selected a date From and To because I want to retrieve selected date from `DATE_OF_SELL` field. When I try to execute it there is an error.

Comment: What error you getting there?

Answer (score 0):

use Parameters, or use >= =< operators.

Parameters is cleaner, and more readable:

```
Command = New OleDbCommand(" insert into tableB select * FROM tableA where DATE_OF_SELL BETWEEN @FROM AND @END", Connection)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FROM", TextBox1.Text)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END", TextBox2.Text)
```

But why are you using TextBox's instead DateTimePicker's? It requires you to perform validation And converted (in different format case) As written by @Vignesh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
Command = New OleDbCommand(" insert into tableB select * FROM tableA where DATE_OF_SELL BETWEEN Convert(DateTime,'" & TextBox1.Text "',105) AND Convert(DateTime,'" & TextBox2.Text "',105)", Connection)
```